# how to detect character encoding between two operating systems?

Tags: c++, qt, character-encoding, blackberry-10

I'm writing an application for BlackBerry 10 using z10 and normal (qt), not cascades. When I read a string from the virtual keyboard, using the keypressevent() function, I convert the first character from the QKeyEveny::text() to a std char. On the device if I do qDebug() «(int) converted_char characters like r are represented by 114. But on my laptop it is 40(i believe) .
Hence if I send a char from the phone to the laptop using tcp, the correct character is never printed, how can I fix this, what is going on?

Comment: when you do conversion to `char` you are loosing data. Show some code so it would be possible to fix it or at least to see how serious your problem. Do you have control over code on both sides? What data standard do you use to communicate?

Comment: Side note: ascii value for r is 114, so I think your issue is on your laptop.

Comment: As I read over my code, I realized that there was actually no problem at all, it was some terrible assumptions that I was making that made it seem as though there was a problem. Every thing works.